# Is there any mention of the sky crying before the Quran?

Tags: text, miracle, islam, pharaoh

I've stumbled upon a miracle claim made by Muslims. The Quran says about Pharaoh and his people that were drowned:

> Neither heaven nor earth wept over them, nor was their fate delayed. (44:29)

And they're saying that the crying was not mentioned in the Bible nor Talmud. But some old texts from pyramids (Utterance 553) mentions the sky crying and earth trembling over a dead pharaoh:

> 1365b. (with) the špn.t and ‘ȝt-jar, which come from the sḥ-ntr for
> thee, that thou mayest become divine. p. 221
>
> 1365c. The sky weeps for thee; the earth trembles for thee;
>
> 1366a. the śmnt.t-woman laments for thee; the great min.t mourns for
> thee;
>
> 1366b. the feet agitate for thee; the hands wave for thee,

They interpret the Quran as referring to the pyramid text and say that Muhammad couldn't have known about it, because people didn't understand hieroglyphs in his time, so the Quran must be from all-knowing god.

I've found in older exegeses to the Quran that the sky cries for 40 days when a believer dies, but doesn't cry for disbelievers. And that the sky cried blood when imam Hussain was killed. And some hadiths about doors in heaven:

> Anas bin Malik narrated that the Messenger of Allah (saw) said: “There
> is no believer except that he has two doors: A door through which his
> deeds ascend, and a door through which his sustenance descends. So
> when he dies they weep for him. That is the meaning of the saying of
> Allah, the Mighty and Sublime: And the heavens and the earth wept not
> for them, nor were they given respite.” (Tirmidhi)

And now my question is whether the motif of the sky or earth crying is really nowhere to be found in Jewish texts?